# Обработчик click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, не могу понять почему не работает обработчик... как только не пробовал.
пробовал так:

```
<script lang="javascript"> $('#selectInput1').click(alert('1')); </script>
```

еще пробовал так:

```
<script src = "js/functions.js"></script>
```

functions.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ajaxFormOptions = {
          success: showResponse,
          resetForm: true
      };
  $('selectInput1').click(function(){alert('lol');});
}
```

Форма:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="text">Имя отправителя</label>
   <div class="jq-selectbox jqselect">
      <input id="selectInput1" class="form-control"></input>
         <div id="SelectDropdown1" class="jq-selectbox__dropdown" style="position: absolute; display:none">
            <ul style="position: relative; list-style: none; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
               <li>1</li>
               <li>2</li>
               <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="help-block">Имя или номер</p>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery подключил? `$('#selectInput1').click(function() { alert('lol'); });`

Comment: @Doofy, 
`<script src = "js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/functions.js"></script>`
при просмотре кода страницы консоль ошибок не выдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант из function.js выглядит лучше всех.
Только селектор нужно с # сделать, все таки id.

Comment: похоже где-то опечатался... делал с #, все точно также но не работало, сейчас, когда скидывал вам пример, писал все заново, не копировал. потом скопировал отсюда пример, вставил в прогу и все заработало) спасибо